# How do I delete repeated elements in a dataframe made by a class-method function?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning, class-method

I have a simple python code for data cleaning. This code imports data from Excel that has the format like this:

```
    product cost   used_by prime
    name    price  gender  yes or no
    name    price  gender  yes or no
    ... and so on
```

afterward I will get a `mylist` using the class function that looks something like this:

```
mylist =    [Item(comic,20.0,male,yes), 
             Item(paint,14.0,male,no), 
             Item(pen,5.0,female,nan), 
             Item(phone case,9.0,nan,no), 
             Item(headphone,40.0,male,yes), 
             Item(coat,nan,male,no),
             Item(comic,15.0,male,yes), 
             Item(nan,15.0,male,no)
             ... and so on]
```

and after all the filter and cleaning I will get a result that looks like this:

```
result = [Item(comic,20.0,male,yes), 
          Item(underwear,15.0,male,yes), 
          Item(comic,15.0,male,yes)
          ... 
          Item(underwear,15.0,male,yes), 
          ...and so on]
```

Here is the code I got so far:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import math
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.XLSX'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True)

df = df.where(df.notnull(), None)
array = df.values.tolist()
print(array)

class Item():
    def has_all_properties(self):
        return bool(self.__name and not math.isnan(self.__cost) and self.__gender and self.__prime)
    def clean(self):
        return bool(self.__name and self.__cost <=20 and self.__gender == "male" and self.__prime == "yes")
    
    def __init__(self, name, cost, gender, prime):
        self.__name = name
        self.__cost = cost
        self.__gender = gender
        self.__prime = prime

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item({self.__name},{self.__cost},{self.__gender},{self.__prime})"

    def __tuple__(self): 
         return self.__name, self.__cost, self.__gender, self.__prime

mylist = [Item(*k) for k in array]

filtered = filter(Item.has_all_properties, mylist)
clean = filter(Item.clean, filtered)
result = list(clean)

t_list = [obj.__tuple__() for obj in result]
print(t_list)

output = pd.DataFrame(t_list, columns =['name', 'cost', 'gender', 'prime'])
print(output)
output.to_excel('clean_data.xlsx', index = False, header = True)
```

In the result, there are two type of repetitive data, one is like the `underwear` which have two exact same lines; and the other one is like the `comic`, with different cost values.

So what I want to do is remove one of the line that are exact the same for case one and keep the line that has the smaller cost value for case 2.

So for case two, I am think of reading the product to identify if they are the same and if they are I then compare their cost and keep the one with smaller value. But I am not sure if that is the right way of doing it.

I am aware that using pandas all the way work but I wish to explore the class function and use the customized data frame.

Can you suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Set` instead of a list, i.e., changing `myList = [Item(*k) for k in array]` to `mySet = {Item(*k) for k in array}`.

Sets do not allow duplicates.

**EDIT**
Make sure to include implementations of `__hash__` and `__eq__` in your `Item` class so that set can know how to determine whether an item has a duplicate.

In your case, the `__eq__` would look something like the following:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
  self.__name == other.__name
  self.__cost == other.__cost
  self.__gender == other.__gender
  self.__prime == other.__prime
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working for you? As it you still have duplicates?

Comment: yes, for example, there are still two lines of Item(underwear,15.0,male,yes) in the set

Comment: I edited the answer to include that you need to make sure the ```Item``` class is comparable; otherwise the set won't know how to tell if the items are the same. So if you add an implementation of ```__eq__``` (and ```__hash__``` too, because I think that's necessary for sets) it should work.

Comment: Thank you, the code is able to solve case one now.